# How does the validator win vote prize?

Tags: vote-account

As we can see, a validator win the vote prize when the validator's uninterruptedly vote stack reach the length of 32.but what if the validator vote on the wrong fork? or the blocks haven't been confirmed , will the validator get his vote prize?

Answer (score 2):

For every correct vote that a validator submits to the network that eventually gets rooted, the validator receives 1 vote credit.

If they vote on the wrong fork or the block isn't confirmed, then by definition the block does not get rooted, so they don't receive a vote credit.

The terminology for vote credits may be a good starting point to learn more: https://docs.solana.com/terminology#vote-credit

Comment: For an example, the validator vote on block A and reach 32, but block A have not been confirmed, will the validator win the vote prize? or if another fork not contains A has been confirmed then what will happen to the vote of A ?

Comment: > For an example, the validator vote on block A and reach 32, but block A have not been confirmed, will the validator win the vote prize?

No, the block must be confirmed by the supermajority to ever be rooted and get the vote credit. If a fork without A reaches a depth of 32 and gets rooted, the validator must abandon that vote and go with the rest of the cluster.

> if another fork not contains A has been confirmed then what will happen to the vote of A?

If another fork gets confirmed, but not rooted, there's still a chance that the cluster switches to the fork with A.